# Issue with variable in a if/else loop in Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String location = "memes more memes Virginia";

    String test = createStateMap(location);
    System.out.println(test);
```

}

```
public static String createStateMap(String loc) {

    loc = loc.toUpperCase();
    String secondLast; // Retrieves potential second to last value 
    String lastWord; // Retrieves last value 
    String state = "failed";
    String trimmed = loc.trim(); // Take off spaces at the end of String
    String o = trimmed.substring(0, trimmed.lastIndexOf(" ")); // Remove last Word in String   EX. "SOUTH CAROLINA" = "SOUTH"
    String otrim = o.trim(); // Take off spaces at the end of String

    if (trimmed.contains("/")){
    secondLast = otrim.substring(otrim.lastIndexOf("/")+1); 
    lastWord = trimmed.substring(trimmed.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
    } else { 
        secondLast = otrim.substring(otrim.lastIndexOf(" ")+1); 
        lastWord = trimmed.substring(trimmed.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
    }




    HashMap<String,String> names = new HashMap<String,String>();
       names.put("ALABAMA", "AL");
       names.put("ALASKA", "AK");
       names.put("ARIZONA", "AZ");
       names.put("ARKANSAS", "AR");
       names.put("CALIFORNIA", "CA");
       names.put("COLORADO", "CO");
       names.put("CONNECTICUT", "CT");
       names.put("DELAWARE", "DE");
       names.put("FLORIDA", "FL");
       names.put("GEORGIA", "GA");
       names.put("HAWAII", "HI");
       names.put("IDAHO", "ID");
       names.put("ILLINOIS", "IL");
       names.put("INDIANA", "IN");
       names.put("IOWA", "IA");
       names.put("KANSAS", "KS");
       names.put("KENTUCKY", "KY");
       names.put("LOUISIANA", "LA");
       names.put("MAINE", "ME");
       names.put("MARYLAND", "MD");
       names.put("MASSACHUSETTS", "MA");
       names.put("MICHIGAN", "MI");
       names.put("MINNESOTA", "MN");
       names.put("MISSISSIPPI", "MS");
       names.put("MISSOURI", "MO");
       names.put("MONTANA", "MT");
       names.put("NEBRASKA", "NE");
       names.put("NEVADA", "NV");
       names.put("NEWHAMPSHIRE", "NH");
       names.put("JERSEY", "NJ");
       names.put("MEXICO", "NM");
       names.put("YORK", "NY");
       names.put("CAROLINA", "NC");
       names.put("DAKOTA", "ND");
       names.put("OHIO", "OH");
       names.put("OKLAHOMA", "OK");
       names.put("OREGON", "OR");
       names.put("PENNSYLVANIA", "PA");
       names.put("RHODEISLAND   ", "RI");
       names.put("CAROLINA", "SC");
       names.put("DAKOTA", "SD");
       names.put("TENNESSEE", "TN");
       names.put("TEXAS", "TX");
       names.put("UTAH", "UT");
       names.put("VERMONT", "VT");
       names.put("VIRGINIA", "VA");
       names.put("WASHINGTON", "WA");
       names.put("VIRGINIA", "WV");
       names.put("WISCONSIN", "WI");
       names.put("WYOMING", "WY");

       System.out.println(secondLast);
    if (names.containsValue(lastWord)){
        state = lastWord;
    } 
    if (names.containsKey(lastWord)){
        if (names.get(lastWord).equals("CAROLINA")){ // Differentiate NC and SC
            if (secondLast.equals("North")){
                state = "NC";
            } else { state = "SC"; }

        } if (names.get(lastWord).equals("DAKOTA")) { // Differentiate ND and SD
            if (secondLast.equals("North")){
                state = "ND";
            } else { state = "SD"; }

        } if (names.get(lastWord).equals("VIRGINIA")) { // Differentiate WV and VA
        if (secondLast.equals("West")){
                state = "WV";
            } else { state = "VA"; }

        } else { state = names.get(lastWord); } 
        }

    return state;}  }
```

I am currently having issues with my code that assigns a state's abbreviations to a variable depending on the String passed into the parameter of the `createStateMap` method. When the `lastWord` String is either Virginia, Dakota, or Carolina they will always be assigned WV, ND, or NC- even if the `secondLast` is not North or West.

Any help would be much appreciated, I have been stuck on this one for a while.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and putting breakpoints at the where it selects the wrong result?

Comment: Your `} if` should be `} else if`.

Comment: @SteveSmith That won't cause a problem (if we're talking about the same, there are a lot), as the condition in the next if will be false.

Comment: `if (names.get(lastWord).equals("VIRGINIA")) {` should be `if (lastWord.equals("VIRGINIA")) {`.

Comment: Agreed, I'm not saying these will solve your problem, but there's enough "code smell" here to open a perfumery. :)

Comment: That worked, thank you very much!

Comment: note if you are using java 1.7 or above you donnot need to use key, value data types in the right side. Like this: `HashMap<String,String> names = new HashMap<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`names.get(lastWord)` already returns "SC" for key "CAROLINA", so your

```
names.get(lastWord).equals("CAROLINA")
```

condition will always return false.

It also makes no sense to put the same key twice in the Map, since the second value will overwrite the first value having the same key.

Why not put the full name of the state as key?

```
   names.put("SOUTH CAROLINA", "SC");
   names.put("NORTH CAROLINA", "NC");
```

In that case

```
state = names.get(fullStateName);
```

will always work and you can eliminate all of those conditions, as long as `fullStateName` contains the full name of the state (either a single word or two words).

If you don't know whether you should search for the last word or the last two words in the `Map`, you can search for the last two words, and if not found, search for the last word :

```
state = names.get(secondLast + " " + lastWord);
if (state == null) {
    state = names.get(lastWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, just as an fyi,

```
names.put("VIRGINIA", "VA");
names.put("WASHINGTON", "WA");
names.put("VIRGINIA", "WV");
```

You're working with a HashMap here, so you can only have 1 value per key. This means the only value you'll get when you extract `VIRGINIA` is `WV` (the last one to be entered). Just put in the full state name, as Eran suggested. I mean, you're already putting in NEWHAMPSHIRE, which is technically two words, so I don't see why you don't want to do the same thing for the Carolinas, Dakotas, and Virginias.

Comment: Thank you, I had the assumption you could have multiple values per key; this way obviously makes so much more sense.